# How to make <Text> tag behave like an HTML inline element in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this simple UI structure:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>

  <Text>A simple fee equal to</Text>
  <View style={{ width: 80 }}>
    <TextInput style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black' }} />
  </View>
  <Text>of any settlement or judgment</Text>

</View>
```

In a small screen, it would show something like this

[image]

As shown in the image above, I expected the text, `of any settlement or judgment`, to not move to the next line.

The closest solution that I could think of was to chunk each text into individual `Text` elements.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>

  <Text>A simple fee equal to</Text>
  <View style={{ width: 80 }}>
    <TextInput style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black' }} />
  </View>

  {'of any settlement or judgment'.split(' ').map((chunk, i) => (
    <Text key={i.toString()}>{chunk} </Text>
  )}

</View>
```

resulting to something like this:

[image]

Question: Is there a better way to achieve what I want? Or is this the only way to solve the problem?

Comment: numOfLines maybe what you need

Comment: Note the : 
<View style={{ with: 80 }}> has a wrong "WIDTH" Spelling

Comment: @flix I don't think that would help

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write it inside a view with a flexDirection:'row' style property or you can wrap it in another Text  like this :

```
<Text>
 <Text>A simple fee equal to</Text>
  <View style={{ width: 80 }}>
    <TextInput style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black' }} />
  </View>
  <Text>Of any settlement or Judgement</Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this solution [would only work in IOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.50/text.html#nested-views-ios-only)